# Angular 2 Sidebar in a new Module

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 project with a login and a homepage. I'm copying + pasting the sidebar all the time to all components.html.

Is there a way to re-use like a component with the sidebar and call it every time i create a new component or is there another way ? The sidebar code is on pastebin: [Sidebar.html](https://pastebin.com/HxKSUXRS)

```
    <!-- ... -->
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="http://www.creative-tim.com" class="simple-text">
                Util FAQ
            </a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                <a routerLink = "/home">
                    <i class="ti-home"></i>
                    <p>Página Principal</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a routerLink = "/perfil">
                    <i class="ti-user"></i>
                    <p>Perfil</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a routerLink = "/programas">
                    <i class="ti-view-list-alt"></i>
                    <p>Programas</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a routerLink = "/submissoes">
                    <i class="ti-text"></i>
                    <p>Submissões</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a routerLink = "/temas">
                    <i class="ti-package"></i>
                    <p>Temas</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a routerLink = "/utilizadores">
                    <i class="ti-server"></i>
                    <p>Utilizadores</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use multiple router-outlets in your `app.component` like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid grid myappbody">
  <!-- Static Nav Bar -->
  <div class="row mynav">
      <router-outlet name="core"></router-outlet>
  </div>

  <!-- Static App Area -->
  <div class="row mymain">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer Area -->
  <div class="row myfooter">
    <router-outlet name="footer"></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using routing like...

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: CoreComponent, outlet: 'core' },
  { path: 'home', component: FooterComponent, outlet: 'footer' },
  { path: '', component: CoreComponent, outlet: 'core' },
  { path: '', component: FooterComponent, outlet: 'footer' },
  { path: 'acct', loadChildren: loadAcctModule },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/acct', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Comment: The problem is if i use it in app component the login page will have the sidebar too, and thats something i dont want to happen....

Comment: You can move it up one level into whatever module you want the sidebar to be on.

Comment: So where do i insert the sidebar html code ? Inside the "core" component.html ?

Comment: That's correct. Create a `core.component.ts` and have it load your `core.component.html` as a template. If you only want it for a specific module you can mimic this technique for any sub-module.

Comment: Normally `CoreComponent` is reserved for any app-wide static pieces you want to include, but that's just a naming convention. The basic idea is to include a `<router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>` in a module's base component, and then have your routing set up to direct a component into that specific router on the root path `''` and `'home'` for the above example.